# Hypothetical question about AJAX/PHP voting systems and Amazon Mechanical Turk

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, voting, mechanicalturk

I'm not too familiar with Amazon Mechanical Turk, but being a JavaScript/PHP developer, it occurred to me that paying for someone to click through could affect simple voting applications (i.e. Yahoo's OMG voting).

Hypothetically speaking, is there a way or method to validate against clicks from this service and block them? For the sake of the question, let's assume the voting system is using a combo of PHP, AJAX and jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing comes to mind, as the people doing the clicking are just that.  Actual People.  You have no programmatic way of differentiating one actual person behind a computer from another person who is getting paid to do this.

At least, not to my knowledge.  To a web server, they both look the same.  You can't rely on a referrer or... anything.  It's just a person mindlessly clicking.

I suppose if your application had multiple things to vote on, you could keep track of votes by IP/session/whatever, and then do a check to make sure you aren't getting an obscene amount from 1 place, but then the people posting listings would just change how many clicks they paid for...

I think you're just screwed.

Comment: Haha, yeah I guess; however someone would have to pay to screw up a rating system. I thought maybe there was something in their API that you could check for on your server, you know? Otherwise you'd just have to implement some sort of confirmation method (i.e. entering an email).

Answer (score 0):

you can secure ur polls with simple lines.

1. User can only vote if he stays on
   page more than 20sec. (javascript)
2. Cookie save that he saved.
3. Ip saved in file/mysql to block him
   from re voting

that's is usually enough to block all spammers away ! or not ?

Comment: #1 is an interesting technique. Do you have a code example? 

#3 However can cause major problems if a host of people share the same IP, as you'll be blocking others too, not just the spammer. And Amazon Turk should ensure most clicks be from different IPs anyway, so that wouldn't work.

Comment: @MindSculpt Not to steal his thunder, but it's been 30 minutes...  I would say the easiest way would be to call the PHP `time()` function when they first load the page and store it in a session variable.  When they try and vote, compare the current `time()` with the session variable.  If the difference is more than 20, they can vote.

Comment: @uscere90 That sounds like a feasible approach. Thanks!

Comment: @MindSculpt Sure thing.  Remember to accept an answer when you feel you've gotten enough input (or make your own if nobody is able to help) - people will be more inclined to answer your questions in the future if they notice you have a high 'accepted answer' percentage.